# Byobu scrollback buffer on Mac - utilize mouse wheel

Tags: ubuntu, mac, byobu

I am using Byobu via SSH on a local mac machine. I am aware of the scrollback feature and I am able to enter the scrollback mode via F7.

However, it is very inconvenient to scroll by a single line only using arrow keys (only mode that works). Would it be possible to bind the mouse scroll there too? Mouse scrolling scrolls the holding terminal window at the moment.

Comment: It would be great to get this to work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/199290/can-mouse-wheel-scrolling-be-enabled-in-byobu tackles linux issues but mac was missing.

Comment: I know this is old, but if anyone comes across this, the following link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124767/5812876

Answer (score 15):

Press the <kbd>F7</kbd> key to enter scrollback mode. Scrollback mode allows you to navigate past output using `vi`-like commands. Here is a quick list of movement commands:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>  (half page up and down)
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>  (full page up and down)

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/byobu.html)

Comment: …and hit `Enter` to exit scrollback mode

Answer (score 1):

Disable scrollback in a Mac terminal:

> Preferences -> Profiles -> Window -> Limit number of rows to: `0`

Press <kbd>F7</kbd> to enter scrolling mode in *byobu* and scroll your mouse with <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit scrolling mode.

I fully realize that this is not the most convenient solution, but that's the best I've found so far.

Comment: The row limit disable does remove the scrolling interaction from the terminal window, however, holding down shift does not do anything in scrolling mode. The cursor does not move, I can only use keyboard.